# Port prototype definition in AUTOSAR

Tags: autosar

I didn't find a definition of port prototype in the standard.

What is a definition of port prototype?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

*PortPrototype is an abstract class having common properties of different types of ports(P, R, PR).*

All these port classes extend PortPrototype class.you can refer AUTOSAR_SWS_RTE.pdf
or Software Component Template for more information

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into the specification of the AUTOSAR Software Component Template. This document can be downloaded off of the AUTOSAR web site.

Answer (score 0):

See [autosar standard 4.3 classic platform](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/4-3/AUTOSAR_TPS_SoftwareComponentTemplate.pdf)

A port prototype is the way that software components can interact and exchange data. A port prototype is a generic concept that in actual use results in e.g. a Client/Server or Sender/Receiver Port.

The data that is transferred in that port is defined by it's port interface.

In the linked .pdf you might want to check chapter 3.2 for more details on software components and their communication.